# How to use google loader properly

Tags: jquery, google-code

I've been using the following for a while:

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I have seen other google loader alternatives e.g. just loading the jQuery itself (note: http):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This alternative means you don't need to call the first example.

Which is the best method to use when using Google loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either.
As mentioned on [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/libraries/devguide.html) under introduction

> The Libraries API provides your applications with stable, reliable,
>   high-speed, globally available access to all of the most popular,
>   open-source JavaScript libraries. Your application can use our very
>   flexible loader google.load() or direct, path-based access to the
>   scripts.

I prefer to load the libraries directly (your second option) as I don't see the need to load google libraries aswell as jquery

Use httpS if your page itself is httpS. Otherwise, there just use http

Answer (score 1):

you have no need of the first line to load the jQuery API through google!
I suggest you use this approach so as to always load the latest stable version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
```

you can also do the same with query ui:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>
```